# Text formatting in Python

Tags: python, text, formatting

I have a file that has the following format:

```
01*13345233000*7677082000*0335
02*1*Ground*Workshop*640.80*11.46*7344
02*2*First*Office/Labs*300.81*14.10*4241
02*3*Ground*Workshop*774.46*11.46*8875
01*13345233000*7677082000*0335
02*1*Ground*Workshop*640.80*11.46*7344
02*2*First*Office/Labs*300.81*14.10*4241
```

I just want to reformat it as follows (Copy the lines that start with 01 to the corresponding 02 lines):

```
02*1*Ground*Workshop*640.80*11.46*7344*01*13345233000*7677082000*0335
02*2*First*Office/Labs*300.81*14.10*4241*01*13345233000*7677082000*0335
02*3*Ground*Workshop*774.46*11.46*8875*01*13345233000*7677082000*0335
02*1*Ground*Workshop*640.80*11.46*734401*13345233000*7677082000*0335
02*2*First*Office/Labs*300.81*14.10*424101*13345233000*7677082000*0335
```

Many thanks for your help.

Kate

Comment: Nothing - I only managed to extract to different files all lines that begin with 01 and 02

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I have so far but its not what I want that's why i haven't posted it before     f_in = open('C:\Original.txt')
f_out = open('C://01.txt',"w")

while 1:
    lines = f_in.readlines()
    if not lines:
        break
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('01'):
            f_out.write(line)

Comment: @user1812613 Hard to read. Better edit your question...

Answer (score 5):

assuming your file is called `textfile.txt` this will create a list called `to_output` which you can write a second file or whatever else you might need to do with it...

```
to_output = []
current_01 = ""

with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        if line.startswith("01"):
            current_01 = line
        elif line.startswith("02"):
            to_output.append(line.strip()+"*"+current_01)

print to_output
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It works fine -The only problem is that the input file is huge and I get a memory error.

Comment: This answer looks good, and can easily be modified to work with large files. Just open a file to write to: `with open('textfile.txt','r') as datafile, open('outfile.txt','w') as outfile:'` and instead of appending to a list just write to the file.

Comment: good shout @Matt; didn't want to do all the work though...